# How can I get Google Drive to display file or folder size?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, google-docs

I noticed that there is a column but it is not populated for neither my folders nor my files.

I want to verify that files and folders I transfer to Google Drive match where they came from.

[image]

If you notice the last column which is `size`, it is not populated or has a `-`.

There is also a `view details` which did not show the size either.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

G Suited Document Editors files (Google Documentos, Google Sheets, Google Slides, Google Forms, Google Drawings, ...) doesn't consume storage quota so Google doesn't track the file size the same way that they do for uploaded files that consume storage quota.

You only can check for a match for G Suite Document Editors:

- file name,
- file type,
- folders parents

Maybe also

- Owner
- Editors, viewers and related sharing settings

But you could use Google Drive API to add custom metadata.

Answer (score 2):

To view Google Drive folder sizes  without having to download your entire Google Drive, have a look at the "preferences" in the "backup and sync" app. (I'm on a Mac, so this may be a little different on the windows version)

[image: Select "Preferences..." from the stacked dots menu of your "Backup and Sync" menu.]

[image: click on "google drive" on the left-hand pane, and on the right-hand pane, select "sync only these folders".]

Notice that list of folders in the "sync only these folders" includes folder sizes for folders that have not been synced over to your computer. :)

This suggests to me that google has a hidden API that exposes the sizes of folders. I bet that the hidden API could be discovered with a debugging proxy tool like Charles and then someone could document it if a bounty is offered.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the problem of displaying the file size in Google Drive. And by chance I found a solution: search for example .pdf files in your Drive. Then left click down on "Storage space" After that the size of each PDF file will be displayed in descending order.